# Find WorkItems that were assigned and finished in the last 30 days

Tags: tfs

I would like to see a list of workitems assigned to a particular person. I would also like get information about when those workitems were completed. Is there any column like assigned_date and finished_date that i could use?

I saw `[Status]='AssignedTo'` but didnt find anything that says when it was assigned and when it was finished

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179044/find-workitems-that-were-assigned-to-x-in-the-last-30-days) provides some info that I am looking for but not everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the operator “Was Ever” that searches for a value in a field in the history of Work Items. Such a query will return all Work Items you were/someone assigned to, even if now they are assigned to a different person.
[image]

However, there is not any `assigned_date` and `finished_date` you could use. Several date and identity fields are set based on workflow states or transitions. You could find all
Date and Iteration Path fields [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#date-and-iteration-path-fields).

You have to use [Revisions - List Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to return the list of fully hydrated work item revisions and fetch the work item assigned and finished time. Finally check if they are in the last 30 days.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?api-version=6.1-preview.3
```